# How to sum up values of a for range function in python

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Basically i want to sum up the result of the expression k=5*x+17 but with different x, like (k=5*3+17) + (k=5*4+17) and so on... so far my code looks like the following.The result needs to be Σ which goes from the range (3,9).

```
for x in range(3,9):
    k=5*x+17
    k+=k
print(k)
```

Comment: but you're  overwriting `k` at each iteration, so in the end the result is just `(5*8+17)*2`

Comment: as mentioned before you are overwriting k in each step, instead of `k=...` you need to do `k += ...` or `k = k + ...` and add the initialization of `k=0` before the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're overwriting `k` at each iteration, so in the end the result is just `(5*8+17)*2`

To perform such a sum, with x varying between 3 and 8 (9 is not included) so it in a generator comprehension and pass the result to `sum`, you'll avoid the nasty side-effects like you just created.

```
result = sum(5*x+17 for x in range(3,9))
```

(of course if you want to include `9` you have to range from `3` to `10`), so depending on the upper boundary, you get `267` or `329`

You can also do that without using `sum` at all using the `n*(n+1)//2` formula for sum of integers from 1 to n and adapting it a la project euler to reduce complexity:

```
start = 3
end = 9 # inclusive
result = ((end*(end+1))//2 - ((start-1)*(start))//2)*5 + (end-start+1)*17
```

Comment: @joaolell please remember to accept an answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

Remembering that the sum of integers between 1 and n is [`n*(n+1)/2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and using some [basic summation equalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#General_manipulations), you can calculate the result directly:

```
>>> (3 + 9 - 1) * (9 - 3) // 2 * 5 + 17 * (9 - 3)
267
```

Answer (score 1):

For a range from i to j and an expression a*x+b, you can do:

```
a*(j-i)*(i+j-1)//2 + b*(j-i)
```

Because what you want is:

Σa*x+b = a*Σx + Σb

Answer (score 0):

```
#Use this simple code
l=[]
for x in range(3,9):
    y = lambda x :5*x+17
    l.append(y(x))

l =sum(l)
print l
```

Comment: this is unnecessary complicated, you don't need list or lambdas to solve it, the code of the OP is basically correct save for 2 little things.

Comment: yes, in this case lambda i not necessary but if expression  becomes complex where we have  iterable datatype then this method will definitely help